# Function on interval

Tags: convex-optimization

I am having trouble with a question, just hope that someone out there is kind enough to help me with it. Thanks in advance!!

Suppose $f := \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is continuous, and $f$ has the following properties:

(i) $f(x) \ge 1$ for all $x$ such that $x \in S$

(ii) there exists an $x$ such that $x \notin S$

Show that $f$ has a global minimizer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , that in (ii) it should read $f(x)<1.$

Let $K:=\{x \in \mathbb R^n: ||x||_{\infty} \le r\}.$ $K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, hence there is $x_0 \in K$ such that

$$(*) \quad f(x_0) = \min f(K).$$

Now assume that $||x_0||_{\infty}=r$. By (i) we see that $f(x_0) \ge 1.$This leads to a contradiction to $(*)$, since, by (ii), there is $x \in K$ with $f(x) <1.$

Therefore $||x_0||_{\infty}<r$. By (ii), there is  $x \in K$ with $f(x) <1.$ Hence

$f(x_0) \le f(x) <1.$

With (i) and $(*)$ we get

$$f(x_0) = \min f( \mathbb R^n).$$